# How to add Unit Text in an input field?

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.3

I want to Programmatically create `Custom Product Attributes` in `Magento 2.3.3` and I want a `Unit/Quantifier` in this input field as well like
[image]

`lbs` in this example.
Its code is

```
<label class="admin__addon-suffix" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}" for="IULEV9M">
            <span data-bind="text: addafter">lbs</span>
        </label>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff about all the configuration for the ui-components form of the weight field inside the product form is happening in the file:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php` in the method `customizeWeightField`.

The arrays which are merged there are formatted exactly on the same way like the ui-components xml file, so you should be able adapt the exact same inside the ui component xml file.

Inside the `customizeWeightField` method i would highlight the following line, this one seems for me to be the additional placeholder-style text which is displayed inside the form field.

```
'addafter' => $this->locator->getStore()->getConfig('general/locale/weight_unit'),
```

So if you want to add this to a field inside a ui-component xml file. The field xml should look somehow like this:

```
        <field name="name" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">adapter</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="addafter" xsi:type="string">some text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```